# Android composable doesnt recompose after deleting item from room db

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, state

I have a room db holds favorite entities and i have a stateflow containing list of favorites in database
and i have another boolean state holds if a specific favorite is in the db but when i delete item from the list, state value doesn't change

here is the code:

firstly MainViewModel holds the list and the isFavorite state:

```
private val _favorites = MutableStateFlow<List<Favorite>>(emptyList())
    val favorites = _favorites.asStateFlow()

    val isFavoriteState : MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false)
```

and then the main composable:

```
fun MainScreen(navController: NavController,city : String){
    val mainViewModel : MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val unitType = mainViewModel.unitType
    mainViewModel.getWeather(city,unitType.value)
    val weatherData = mainViewModel.data.value.data
    val dayIndex = mainViewModel.dayIndex
    val favorites = mainViewModel.favorites.collectAsState()



    if(weatherData!=null){
        val isFavorite = rememberSaveable{mutableStateOf(false)}
        mainViewModel.isFavoriteState.value = favorites.value.contains(Favorite(weatherData.city.name,weatherData.city.country))
        Log.d("Fav","is favorite = ${mainViewModel.isFavoriteState.value}")
        Scaffold(topBar = { WeatherTopBar(title = weatherData.city.name, country = weatherData.city.country,
            isMain = true, navController = navController,
            isFavorite = mainViewModel.isFavoriteState,
            onAdd = {
                mainViewModel.addFavorite(Favorite(weatherData.city.name,weatherData.city.country))
                mainViewModel.isFavoriteState.value = true
            },
            onDelete = {
                mainViewModel.isFavoriteState.value = false
                    mainViewModel.deleteFavorite(Favorite(weatherData.city.name,weatherData.city.country))

            }
```

in the top bar i have a favorite button:

```
fun WeatherTopBar(title : String,
                  country : String = "",
                  isMain : Boolean,
                  navController: NavController,
                  isFavorite : MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false),
                  onDelete : () -> Unit = {},
                  onAdd : () -> Unit = {},
                  onBackClick : () -> Unit = {}){
    val isExpanded = remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }
    if(isExpanded.value){
        WeatherDropdownMenu(navController = navController, expanded = isExpanded)
    }
    TopAppBar(title = {Text(text = if(country=="") title else "$title, $country")},
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        elevation = 4.dp,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
        actions = {
            if(isMain){
                if(isFavorite.value){
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        onDelete()
                    }) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Favorite,"Favorite Exists",
                            tint = Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.4f)
                        )
                    }
                }else{
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        onAdd()
                    }) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.FavoriteBorder,"Favorite Not Exists",
                            tint = Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.4f)
                        )
                    }
                }
```

when i delete the favorite from the db, isFavoriteState value still remains true but when i add a non existing favorite to the db state value changes accordingly.
how can i fix this?